# Why flatten gets rid of mapped values?

Tags: dart, petitparser

I am trying to parse a sentence and, at the same time, convert numbers to their digit representation.

As a simple example I want the sentence

> three apples

parsed and converted to

> 3 apples

With this code simple code I can actually parse the sentence correctly and convert *three* in *3*, but when I try to flatten the result, *3* is reverted back to *three*.

```
Parser three() => string('three').trim().map((value) => '3');
Parser apples() => string('apples').trim();
Parser sentence = three() & apples();

// this produces Success[1:13]: [3, apples]
print(sentence.parse('three apples'));

// this produces Success[1:13]: three apples
print(sentence.flatten().parse('three apples'));
```

Am I missing something? Is *flatten* behavior correct?

Thanks in advance
L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the documented behavior of [flatten](https://pub.dev/documentation/petitparser/latest/petitparser.parser/FlattenParserExtension/flatten.html): *It discards the result of the parser, and returns a sub-string of the consumed range in the input being read.*

From the question it is not clear what you expect instead?

- You might want to use the [token](https://pub.dev/documentation/petitparser/latest/petitparser.parser/TokenParserExtension/token.html) parser: `sentence.token().parse('three apples')`. This will yield a `Token` object that contains both, the parsed list `[3, 'apples']` through [Token.value](https://pub.dev/documentation/petitparser/latest/petitparser.core/Token/value.html) and the consumed input string `'three apples'` through [Token.input](https://pub.dev/documentation/petitparser/latest/petitparser.core/Token/input.html).
- Alternatively, you might want to transform the parsed list using a custom [mapping function](https://pub.dev/documentation/petitparser/latest/petitparser.parser/MapParserExtension/map.html): `sentence.map((list) => '${list[0]} ${list[1]}')` yields `'3 apples'`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. 
What I'm trying to achieve is parsing a bit more complex sentence, converting all numbers expressed as words in their numeric counterpart.
For example in _I need three bags of apples_ I want to recognize _three_ as _3_ and _bags of apples_.

My first approach was to write a recognizer for all numbers, usign _map_ to convert them in digits, then _flatten_ the outermost result.
Is there anything wrong with this idea?
Since this doesn't work, I managed to flatten piece by piece the expression that might surround the numbers (in my language, of course).

Comment: Yes, you don't want to flatten the outermost result, only the individual parts.